# Un-edit an array to how it was when it was created

Tags: python, arrays, restore

I have a 2D array which is edited at certain points throughout my program. When I get to a certain point in my program, I would like to 'un-edit' the array so it is as it was when the array was created.
e.g.

```
myArray = [[0, 0, 0, 0], # myArray as it is programmed in my script 
           [0, 2, 0, 2]]
... #Code runs, array is edited.
```

now my array looks like...

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

and then an event happens which causes me to want to change my array back to its original state. I could create a copy of myArray at the beginning of the program and load that, but that would be very impractical as I have tens of similar arrays which need to act the same way, and I may need to un-edit the arrays more than once, which would mean I would have hundreds of copies. I don't know any way to do this practically.

Comment: You've got two options: save the original state, or save a reversible journal of all the modifications.  Saving the original state is probably going to be the easier option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adopt a "copy on write" approach:

1. Reset will point back to the original array which is a single instance for all.
2. Editing an array will create a copy from the original one. Then modifying it won't affect the original instance.

```py
original = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 2]]
def edit(my_array):
    if id(my_array) == id(original):
        my_array = original.copy()
    # ... edit the array

def reset(my_array):
    my_array = original
```

where `my_array` is the actual working copy that can be edited and is different between users.